# Table for both 2-person and multi-person games

Tags: chess

Is there a type of table that can be arranged for both 2-person games, like chess and then re-arranged for a round-table game like Dungeons & Dragons?

I have looked at trapezoidal tables. They do ok when two are placed together for roundtable, but they do not work efficiently in 2-player mode.

Comment: What's wrong with a normal rectangular table? Sit across from each other for chess, sit round the table with the DM at the head for D&D.

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered rhombus tables? One alone is excellent for two people.

If you then require a greater amount of tablespace for four people or need to fit six-plus people at a round table, three rhombuses together make a hexagon.

The hexagon can then be extended by adding two more tables to two adjacent sides, allowing larger and larger subtables to be added, or crescents around a central game manager or leader to be formed.

Comment: What do you mean by a "rhombus table"? A rhombus shape is a diamond. If you are talking about trapezoidal tables I already addressed that in my question.

Comment: I think rhombus (or diamond) is what was meant. Three rhombuses can make a hexagon: http://lh5.ggpht.com/-mDQhY6b_kgg/T_HoofXaoRI/AAAAAAAAIQE/yWEKPJ8PZe0/blue_thumb.jpg?imgmax=800

Comment: Also here's how to extend with two more rhombuses: http://st.depositphotos.com/1002927/4077/v/950/depositphotos_40777337-stock-illustration-4-rhombus-pieces-5-options.jpg

Comment: @TylerDurden If you really want to get into semantics, a diamond is a certain type of pentagon that looks like a cross-section of the gem. The rhombus is what most people mistakenly call a diamond.

Comment: Where do you buy rhombus tables? Also not just any rhombus will do, it has to have a 30 degree acute angle, right? Also, does a rhombus make a good 2 player table?

Comment: Google "rhombus tables buy" and see what pops up. There's also symmetric or isosceles trapezoids, both work fine for two-player games, preferences may depend on exact games.